# How do I say vidui in Selichos in a meaningful way?

Tags: tefilla, how-to, selichot, kavana-concentration, viduy-confession

We say *vidui* three times in *selichos*. Many words are uttered in a relatively short time. How can we do this in a meaningful way that is not "*vidui peh*"?

I have heard tell of one of the *gedolei Torah* that in the *vidui* of everyday *Tachanun*, he said only one word of the “*oshamnu, bogadnu*” prayer. Is that a *derekh* for non-gedolim?

Comment: You could always switch to the Chabad selichos nusach, which says "ashamnu" only once per day... :)

Comment: @Alex, I assume you're kidding. The particular _nusach_ one uses would (for most people) have the force of _minhag_, no?

Comment: @msh210: actually, there are halachic precedents for switching nuschaos - after all, there was such a change when Chassidus came along and advocated Nusach Ari, where until then pretty much all European Jews used Nusach Ashkenaz. The whole issue is discussed in various halachic works (will have to look for sources). But yes, in this case I was kidding.

Comment: I asked a LOR He said he only says one set of oshamnu

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I have heard that is Minhag haGra as well.

Comment: @DoubleAA Bmchilas kvodo, it makes a lot of sense too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Learn the meaning behind the vidui before saying it.
2. Buy a sefer that translates them or an interlinear siddur, and daven from that.
3. Write your own commentary to them whilst learning the meanings.

Comment: Moshe Yitzhak, thanks for the suggestions and welcome to the site. I hope you stick around and enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

> "Better a small number of prayers with concentration, than many without concentration." (Shulchan Aruch OH 1:4) "If... one estimates that he will not be able to concentrate for a large number of prayers, and [therefore] says only a few but with concentration, Hashem considers it as if he... said many prayers with concentration" (Mishna Brurah there)

In practice, I think this means to say vidui (and all of selichot) at the pace which allows you to concentrate best. And don't worry if you end up saying only part of the words. (But make sure what you do say is the important parts, for example I would think that the paragraph ending "aval anachnu veavoteinu hatanu" and a single "ashamnu" paragraph are key things to say)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Shlomo! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes. I had always understood OH 1:4 as referring to Tikkun Chatzos from the earlier seifim but I accept that it can be taken as an independent halocho.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok not according to this https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/mm/samples/MachzorYomKippurSample.pdf page 12

Comment: @JoshuaPearl Kedarkom bakodesh.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I don't understand what that means

Comment: @JoshuaPearl It is the proud and holy characteristic of those from Ashkenaz (= yekkes) to place a high value on their traditions.